# Como colocar logo no cabeçalho?

Tags: html, css

Possuo um site onde uso dois cabeçalhos para mostrar minhas opções para o usuário, mas me deparei com um problema, preciso colocar o logo da empresa e não estou conseguindo fazer, preciso que a logo fique em um tamanho proporcional ao cabeçalho, se coloco no primeiro ou no segundo a logo fica pequena.

Tentei criar uma estrutura, mas meus conhecimentos de CSS não ajudaram muito, tentei algo como isso:

```
<style>
.Geral {
    height:120px;

}

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    background-image:url(images/anc.fw.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#superior {
    float: left;
    width: 1005px;
    height: 60px;
}
#inferior {
    float: left;
    width: 1005px;
    height: 60px;

}

</style>
```

Falando pode ser que eu não consiga exemplificar o que preciso, por isso vou disponibilizar uma imagem.

O site é [este](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/) e o que tentei fazer foi isto:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode deixar o seu `header` e apenas posicionar os `#logo`, `#superior`, `#inferior` dentro do `header`.

```css
header, div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 1220px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 120px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  top: 0px;  
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#superior {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 120px;
  
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}

#inferior {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 120px;   
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}


#superior, #inferior {
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="superior">
    Superior
  </div>
  <div id="inferior">
    Inferior
  </div>
</header>
```

Tomei a liberdade de aplicar algumas alterações no estilo da sua pagina usando o `Developer Tools` do Opera, segue a imagem da janela do mesmo já com as alterações aplicadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu apaguei a `div.hidden-header`, pois como ela te um `height` fixo, ela estava empurrando o `header.clearfix` para baixo... caso prefira, pode simplesmente remover o height do `div.hidden-header` ou aplicar um `position: absolute` ao `header.clearfix`.

Por fim, adicionei uma `div#logo` a sua logo deverá ficar dentro dele, e o valor do `width` da `div#logo`, `left` do `div.nav-top:nth-child(0)` e `left` do `div.nav-top:nth-child(1)` devem ser iguais, de preferencia use a largura da imagem do logo.

Comment: Como posso postar o exemplo de como a minha página está ficando depois das dicas informadas? Ainda não consegui, mas gostaria de postar para possível ajuda, edito a minha pergunta colocando o código atual? Creio que deixaria descaracterizada.

Comment: @adventistapr, atualizei a resposta com uma edição aplicada direto ao seu HTML.

Comment: Olá@TobyMosque, não estou conseguindo identificar onde estão essas opções div.nav-top:nth-child(0) e left do div.nav-top:nth-child(1) para fazer  a alteração.

Comment: Este e um seletor css, :nth-child() selecioma um elemento pelo indice, entao estava me referindo a primeira e a segunda div com a classe nav-top

Comment: Olá @TobyMosque, obrigado pela ajuda e grande paciência, fiz as alterações solicitadas, ficaram legais, mas tenho agora um novo problema, acesse: http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/ e redimensione até a menor resolução e tente navegar pelas opções do menu, por favor.

Answer (score 5):

Tenta essa solução aqui:

```
<header class="clearfix">
    <div class="logo" style="
    background-color: #59218D;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    z-index: 10000;
">

  </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MenuUm"> <i class="icon-menu-1"></i> </button>
          <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img alt="" src="images/anc.fw.png"></a> --> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="MenuUm">
          <div class="search-side" style="margin-top: 0px;"> <a href="#" class="show-search"><i class="icon-search-1"></i></a>
            <div class="search-form">
              <form autocomplete="off" role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="#">
                <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Buscar...">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li> <a href="catalogos.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">catálogos e manuais</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="cores.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">cores e linha</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="garantia.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">garantia e uso</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MenuDois"> <i class="icon-menu-1"></i> </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="MenuDois"> 
          <!-- Início da Lista de Navegação-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li> <a href="index.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">INÍCIO</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="empresa.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">EMPRESA</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="produtos.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">PRODUTOS</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="representantes.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">REPRESENTANTES</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="encontrar.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">ONDE ENCONTRAR</a> </li>
            <li><a href="contato.php" style="padding-top: 28px; padding-bottom: 28px;">CONTATO</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Ficou assim:

[image: Imagem exemplo]

No caso eu usei uma cor para demonstrar, mas é só trocar por uma imagem.

**Explicação:**

- Criei uma div nova para alocar a imagem com um `backgroud´.
- Usei o z-index para deixar a imagem por cima das outras duas divs.
- Com `Position: Absolute` deixei ele estático na posição.

**Observação:**

No responsivo ele precisa de alguns ajustes, porém poucos ajustes. Você pode fazer a logo ficar para cima da navbar no responsivo, acredito que seria a melhor solução.

Substitui todo o header por esse código.

Comment: Olá @GiovanniBernini, obrigado pela grande ajuda, mas me diga uma coisa, se possível, como posso deixar a logo acima da navbar?

Comment: @adventistapr Você pode usar css com media queries para arrumar isso, por exemplo `@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px) {.logo{float:none; position: relative;}}` Você controla que em certo tamanho de tela, tal coisa irá mudar. No exemplo que eu dei, entre 400 e 600px a classe logo, não vai ter mais o `float: left` e o `position: absolute`, logo a div do logo, não vai mais ficar do lado em cima das outras divs.

Comment: Olá novamente @GiovanniBernini, devo estar fazendo algo errado, mas a alteração que fiz como código sugerida não surtiu efeito.

Answer (score 1):

Agora que notei que é uma questão duplicada, então vou migrar minha resposta para cá, já que este tópico está mais desenvolvido.

Outro modo de obter o resultado seria:

Primeiramente, se você pretende deixar o seu trabalho *reponsivo*, ou seja, acessível em *mobile*, não é recomendável utilizar um valor de `width` fixo, como você fez nas `divs` `#logo`, `#superior` e `#inferior`, pois quando o website for acessado em mobile, ele terá um "scroll" horizontal. Utilize % ao invés disso.

Quanto a sua dúvida em si, a ideia é que você crie um bloco para armazenar todo o conteúdo. Logo, menu superior e inferior.

Dentro dela você terá ainda 2 sub blocos para armazenar, sendo 1 para o logo e outro para os 2 menus. Depois basta dividir os 2 menus com largura 100% dentro do bloco destinado apenas ao menu.

Assim você não cria dependência de `position` ou entre os diferentes conteúdos (menu e logo).

Fiz um exemplo que está funcionando com a ideia geral disso, dê uma olhada e veja se resolve o seu problema: http://jsfiddle.net/f19tc70y/1/